# WPF control on top of Windows control

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I have a main window

```
<Window >
     <Canvas x:Name="topCanvas" Background="Black">
        <Grid x:Name="mainGrid" Width="{Binding ElementName=topCanvas, Path=ActualWidth}" Height="{Binding ElementName=topCanvas, Path=ActualHeight}">
  </Grid>
        <Canvas 
            Width="{Binding ElementName=topCanvas, Path=ActualWidth}"
            Height="{Binding ElementName=topCanvas, Path=ActualHeight}" 
            Name="MessageField" PreviewMouseMove="MessageField_PreviewMouseMove_1"    
            >                
        </Canvas>
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

mainGrid is used to host other controls. Basically it has a tab control which is used to host the windows as well as the wpf controls in the tab item. Now I want a pop up control which when comes up should come on top of all the controls, wpf as well as windows control.

Now I have a user control which I am able to use as pop-up but the problem with the control is, it is not coming on the top of the Windowscontrols. It comes on top of wpf controls.

```
 MoveableMessageBox userControl = new MoveableMessageBox();
            System.Windows.Controls.Canvas.SetZIndex(userControl, (int)1);
            MessageField.Children.Add(userControl);
```

Kindly suggest how can I make this control on the top of windows control as well.

[image: WIth Windows Control]

[image: With WPF control]

Comment: You can add a screenshot?

Comment: Did you consider deriving the popup from `Window` rather than `UserControl` and assigning the main window to its `Owner` property?

Comment: @daniele3004 please find the images attached

Comment: You'd want to use a message box made by you? As a normal message box but with the content you want. That's right? @Vikram

Comment: @daniele3004 - Yes sir but the pop up should be drag able on the screen

Comment: Why not create a  Window(Form) and do ShowDialog? @Vikram

Comment: This is one of the standard "airspace" problems.  You cannot overlap a window with a WPF control.  A top-level window is required, you need to use a Window instead of a UserControl.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you just want a custom Dialog Window. Luckily for you, these are very simple to create in WPF. Just extend the `Window` class like this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.Views.PopupWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="PopupWindow" Height="300" Width="300" Background="LightGreen" 
            WindowStyle="None" ResizeMode="NoResize">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="Message" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
            VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </Grid>
</Window>

public partial class PopupWindow : Window
{
    public PopupWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        PreviewMouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(PopupWindow_PreviewMouseMove);
    }

    private void PopupWindow_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Mouse.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed) DragMove();
    }
}
```

The `DragMove` method enables users to move the borderless `Window`, which will be displayed in top of *all* other `Window`s. You can display it like this:

```
PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow();
popup.ShowDialog();
```

Of course, this is a simple, incomplete example and I'm going to leave it up to you to finish it. For example, there is no close `Button` on this `Window`, so you'll have to add that (use ALT+F4 to close it until then). You'll also need to return the `DialogResult` value when the `Window` is closed, but you can find out all that you still need to do from the [Dialog Boxes Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969773(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN.