# How can we show UWP user control on vertical-top edge of the parent window?

Tags: wpf, xaml, uwp, xaml-islands

Following `XAML` in this [Microsoft tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/host-custom-control-with-xaml-islands) is showing too much gap between the top edge of the parent window and the `UWP user control`. **Question**: How can we make the user control align to the top edge of parent window? **Remark**: The `VerticalAlignment="Top"` in the `StackPanel` below does not help. This question is something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26989585/1232087) post but in a different context.

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="ClassLibUWP_inside_WPF.MyUserControl1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:ClassLibUWP_inside_WPF"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:winui="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignWidth="400" Height="329">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="211*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="189*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Background="LightCoral" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <TextBlock>This is a simple custom UWP control</TextBlock>
            <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Height="93" Width="100"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind XamlIslandMessage}" FontSize="50"></TextBlock>
            <winui:RatingControl Height="32" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**When you run the app built in the above tutorial, you get the following screen showing the above UWP user control**:

[image]

**I would instead like to display it as follows** [notice about no gap between window title and the red stack panel]:

[image]

Comment: Do you have a complete sample, together with used packages? WinUI has alpha release only, I don't think that it's stable right now

Comment: Btw, why do you need to place it into the `Grid`? Have you tried to run the sample with `StackPanel` inside user control only?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I think, the above linked tutorial is talking about the latest stable version of WinUI that is version 2.2. Alpha release is WinUI 3.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `UserControl` has a fixed height that is smaller than the height of the window and thus is vertically centered in the window. Setting `VerticalAlignment="Top"` on the `WindowsXamlHost` should give what you want.